# Cannot convert return expression of type 'CountableClosedRange<Int>' to return type 'Int?' in Switch-case

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, uipickerview

I am trying to return ranges of values when the user select from pickerview. 
I used switch-case statements. 
My question is about, how to return ranges of values in return statement?

Here is my code. It is not correct since I got this error, Cannot convert return expression of type 'CountableClosedRange' to return type 'Int?'

```
  private func price(from string: String) -> Int? {
    switch string {
    case "less than 100":
        return 0 ... 100 // the error is here
    case "500-100":
        return 100 ... 500
    case "1000-500":
        return 500 ... 1000
    case "3000-1000":
        return 1000 ... 3000
    case "5000-3000":
        return 3000 ... 5000
    case "larger than 5000":
        return (I don't know)
    case _:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to return a range then you should declare the return type as a range.

Comment: The error is obvious, and the error message tells you exactly what it is. You are saying that you will return an `Int?`, but `0 ... 100` is not an Int, it's a range.

Comment: Well none of the return statements would compile except for `return nil`. Change the function return type to Change the return type to `CountableClosedRange<Int>?`

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. I fixed it as in the accepted answer, and worked perfect! Thank you.

Comment: You can use `default:` instead of the wildcard pattern `case _:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what sense your switch cases are supposed to make, but this, though conceptually nonsensical in my opinion, at least will compile:

```
private func price(from string: String) -> CountableClosedRange<Int>? {
    switch string {
    case "less than 100":
        return 0 ... 100 // the error is here
    case "500-100":
        return 100 ... 500
    case "1000-500":
        return 500 ... 1000
    case "3000-1000":
        return 1000 ... 3000
    case "5000-3000":
        return 3000 ... 5000
    case "larger than 5000":
        return 5000 ... Int.max
    case _:
        return nil
    }
}
```